# Data Handling and API Usage Basics

Tags: database, laravel, vue.js

I am working on a ticketing system based on Laravel and VueJS. I would have a foundation question, where I would like to get your opinion on.

**Scenario**

Via my API I can get all tickets in a database table to process them dynamically in my frontent. Every ticket can have a different status. The user will get a summary in numbers displayed on a dashboard (20 tickets open, 40 closed etc.)

**Question**

I would be interested in the setup of the business logic. Where would I do the calculation of the summaries? Would I create an API Request that will return all this information, which then is calcuated on server side? Or is the way to do it, getting all the data from the table and working it out on the front end side (filters etc.)

What is a best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return some properties in your calls where these calculations can happen. Like Instagram or Facebook that have properties with pagination info, number of medias, etc...